# CSS Flexbox - Responsive margin

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

```css
.portfolio {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #ddd0a7;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgb(238, 241, 210);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class='portfolio'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class="box zone game"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone game"><img src=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class="box zone writting"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone writting"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone writting"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone writting"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone writting"><img src=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
      <div class="box zone roleplay"><img src=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an issue with my CSS. I'm trying to build a portfolio and here is

What I have
[image: what I have]

What I want
[image: what I want].

So it's a big container, with three columns inside and content inside the columns. I'm using flexbox, it's responsive when I reduce the window. But I want the columns to be smaller and centered, and still, be responsive.
I tried adding a margin to my big container, I tried to reduce the width of my columns, but those solutions make the whole thing unresponsive on a smaller screen. I tried using the media queries to delete the `margin` if the screen gets smaller, but there is always a moment where my content disappears, to reappear when the window hits the width specified in the `@media` queries.

My best result so far was with a `margin-top` of 15px, and a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of 20%, but then my content gets really small when I downsize the window.

Comment: As one of the solutions. Add `justify-content: center` to `.row` for centering. And add `flex: 0 1 300px` to `.column`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding this to your `.row`

```
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

also add

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/craig_codes/pen/qBqjNJe

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 992px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Add this.

You can change the **max-width** as you need. The **margin: 0 auto** will keep the box horizontally center because the left and right margin is auto